# How to find the original file of a soft link?

Tags: symbolic-link

For example, I have a file `a`, and I do the followings.

```
ln -s a b
ln -s b c
ln -s c d
```

If I use `readlink d`, I will get `c`. So I have to run many times to get `a`.

Is there an easy way to get `a`?

Update:

If I want to locate the original file of `/usr/bin/java`, I have to do it many times to get `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`. The files and links are *not* in the same folder.

Comment: For macOS Catalina try - readlink -n `which command`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command for following chains of links is named `namei`<sup>[ManPage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/namei.1.html)</sup>. Examples:

```
$ touch a
$ ln -s a b
$ ln -s b c
$ ln -s c d
$ namei ./d
f: ./d
 d .
 l d -> c
   l c -> b
     l b -> a
       - a
$ namei /usr/bin/java
f: /usr/bin/java
 d /
 d usr
 d bin
 l java -> /etc/alternatives/java
   d /
   d etc
   d alternatives
   l java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
     d /
     d usr
     d lib
     d jvm
     d java-7-openjdk-i386
     d jre
     d bin
     - java
```

Comment: Maybe this is what I am looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following shell function:

```bsh
readmultilink () {
    linkfile="$1"
    if [ ! -L "$linkfile" ]; then 
        echo "$linkfile is not a simbolik link" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    until [ ! -L "$linkfile" ]; do
        lastlinkfile="$linkfile"
        linkfile=$(readlink "$lastlinkfile")
    done
    readlink "$lastlinkfile"
}
```

Add this function at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file if you want to use it every time when you open the terminal.

Usage:

```
readmultilinks file_name
```

As example, for your example, `readmultilinks d`, `readmultilinks c`, and `readmultilinks b` will return `a`, but `readmultilinks a` will return `a is not a simbolik link`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
readlink -f /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need find instead:

```
$ find -L . -samefile d
./b
./c
./d
./a
```

Or:

```
$ ls -i d
143075 d
$ find . -follow -print -inum 143075
.
./b
./c
./d
./a
```

Both cases the original file is the last one.

Comment: These cases will only locate files in the given folder.

Comment: @eccstartup you only have to change `.` for the directory you like, ie `/`, but they will take time.

Comment: What is the result on your computer? If the link is `/usr/bin/java`?

Comment: @eccstartup beats me... I don't have/use java, Also, it will depends what version of java you install, but I gave you a general solution for all sort of problems.

Comment: Well, I get many many results. If I redirect the result into a file, the size of the file is over 10MB, and it is increasing because I kill it with `Ctrl+C`.